# how can I write code of terminal inside python script at windows

Tags: python, windows, terminal

How can I send this code below as a command from python script to be run on tirminal:

cd %HOMEPATH%

conda install git

git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/demucs

cd demucs

conda env update -f environment-cpu.yml

conda activate demucs

python.exe -m demucs.separate -d cpu --dl "PATH_TO_AUDIO_FILE_1" ["PATH_TO_AUDIO_FILE_2" ...]

I applied this code:

```
import os
os.system("cd %HOMEPATH%")
os.system("conda install git")
os.system("git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/demucs")
os.system("cd demucs")
os.system("conda env update -f environment-cpu.yml")
os.system("conda activate demucs")
os.system("python.exe -m demucs.separate -d cpu --dl 'C:/Users/Arwa_Analyst/Downloads/CAPSTONE PROJECT/research samples/audioDataset/Eval_S_Wav/-1hDIl9Udkw.wav' ")
```

and I got this errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrfqG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J75VC.png)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os

os.system("cd %HOMEPATH%")
os.system("conda install git")
#...
#..
```

You can use the import `os` package and use `system` function to run terminal commands from python.

Comment: I tried this but the python can not identify the folders path such as (conda env update -f environment-cpu.yml) and (python.exe -m demucs.separate)

Comment: Could you add the code and the error you had to the question? @ArwaAl-Ghamdi

Comment: I did what you said